# How do I group these values

Tags: sql-server

I have to take a person's race, gender, age range and
I have to take:

Race 1 - Gender 1 - Age Range

Race 1 - Gender 2 - Age Range

Race 2 - Gender 1 - Age Range

Race 2 - Gender 2 - Age Range

and turn it into:

### Group # | Average Age

Group 1 | 20-30

Group 2 | 40-50

Group 3 | 30-40

Group 4 | 40-50

The age is inputted as 20-30, 30-40, 40-50 so I have to find the most repeated string but I don't know how to tie it all together in 2 columns and 4 rows. I'm still new and would like to learn. Can anyone explain how I can do this?

Edit:
[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YddB3.png) [Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaOUn.png) [Desired End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtf7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on your table structure but perhaps something like this would work.

```
select GroupType, age
from (select race + gender as GroupType , age, count(*) as frequency,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY race + gender ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
        from tbl
        group by race + gender, age) g
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: My result when entering the data shows that the age column is invalid because it is not contained in either aggregate function or the Group by clause. What causes this pop up because several things that I tried made this pop up as well.

Comment: It works now but I need 4 rows with a male and female of both races. Is there a way i can reorganize the race and gender into a group just called Group 1?

Comment: @MaxMani Concatenating `race + gender` together like this should give you all possible combinations in the `GROUP BY`.  So if you only have two possible `Race` values and two possible `Gender` values, this should only give you 4 rows.  I don't know what your data exactly looks like though, so you'll have to play around with this.

Comment: There are multiple races but the code above only provided with 1 row, It just stated, RaceGender | Age Group. And is it possible to group the 2 and rename the grouping with another name? I updated the question with pictures, I had to change seqnum to <5 to get the desired amount of columns but it's repeating that race.

Comment: I've added a `PARTITION` to the query.

Comment: Wow that worked out so much better. Is there a way to restrict it to the 2 races because the query is only for those 2 groups?

Comment: Add a WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank your for your help.  It's working exactly how I want it now. I wish I could upvote or something but My account is new. Thank you.